# Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /actividad/planificacion/guardarplanificacion/

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

Estoy generando una tabla para enviarla por POST, sin embargo, al momento que envió me sale que el código CSRF es incorrecto o erróneo, ya he probado de algunas maneras y no tengo una solución correcta, adjunto el código.
Views.py

```
class GuardarPlanificacion(TemplateView):
# Llamar al metodo para transacciones en base de datos
@transaction.atomic
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print("Entro a guardar planificación")
    datosplanificacion = {}
    _transaccion = transaction.savepoint()
    try:
        valor = request.POST.get('datosplaning', None)
        print(valor)
        datosplanificacion = json.loads(request.POST['datosplaning'])
        print(datosplanificacion)
        fechaactual = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        print('pasa')
        for semana in datosplanificacion["semana"]:
            semanaactividad = int(semana)
        print('pasa')
        for planifica in datosplanificacion['planificacion']:
            print('entra')
            # print(planifica['actividad'])
            actividad = planifica['actividad']
            fechainicio = planifica['fechainicio']
            fechafin = planifica['fechafin']
            detalleplanificacion = Detalleplanificacionactividad(
                secuencial_actividad=Actividad.objects.get(
                    nombre=actividad),
                secuencial_planificacion=Planificacion.objects.get(
                    Q(fechainicio__lte=fechaactual) & Q(fechafin__gte=fechaactual) & Q(numerosemana=semanaactividad)), # noqa
                fechainicio=fechainicio, fechafin=fechafin)
            detalleplanificacion.save()
        transaction.savepoint_commit(_transaccion)
        datosplanificacion['result'] = "OK"
        datosplanificacion['message'] = "¡Registro de actividad \
                            guardado correctamente!"
        messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, datosplanificacion['message'])
        # Responder solicitud pedida por AJAX
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(datosplanificacion), content_type="application/json")
    except Exception as error:
        print("Error al guardar-->transaccion: " + str(error))
        print(type(error))    # la instancia de excepción
        print(error.args)     # argumentos guardados en .args
        print(error) 
        transaction.savepoint_rollback(_transaccion)
        datosplanificacion['message'] = "¡Ha ocurrido un error al tratar de ingresar los datosplanificacion de la persona!"
        datosplanificacion['error'] = "Transacción: " + str(error)
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(datosplanificacion), content_type="application/json")
```

JAVASCRIPT - JQUERY

```js
$("#my_form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
    var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
    var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
    //var form_data = new FormData(this); //Encode form elements for submission
    
    let semana = document.getElementById('semana').innerHTML;
    var datos = {
        'planificacion': [],
        'semana':semana
    };

    $("#mainTable tbody tr").each(function (index) {
        var actividad, cobertura, responsable, requerido, fechainicio, fechafin;
        $(this).children("td").each(function (index2) { // Recorre cada fila y a su vez cada columna
            // Obtiene el indice de la columna en la que esta para archivar el valor en una variable
            switch (index2) {
                case 0:
                    actividad = $(this).text();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    cobertura = $(this).text();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    responsable = $(this).text();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    requerido = $(this).text();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    $(this).find("input").each(function () {
                        fechainicio = this.value
                    });
                    break;
                case 5:
                    $(this).find("input").each(function () {
                        fechafin = this.value
                    });
                    break;
            }
            //$(this).css("background-color", "#ECF8E0");
        })
        //console.log(actividad + ' - ' + cobertura + ' - ' + responsable + ' - ' + requerido + ' - ' + fechainicio + ' - ' + fechafin);
        // Añade cada uno de los datos obtenidos de la tabla dentro del arreglo de datos creando un JSON
        datos.planificacion.push({
            'actividad': actividad,
            'cobertura': cobertura,
            'responsable': responsable,
            'requerido': requerido,
            'fechainicio': fechainicio,
            'fechafin': fechafin
        });
    })
    console.log(datos)
    

    $.ajax({
        type: request_method,
        url: post_url,
        data: {'datosplaning':JSON.stringify(datos), csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
        success: function (data) {
            if (data['result'] == "OK") {
                console.log('Proceso completado')
                swal("Planificación Creada Correctamente!", "Da Clic en el boton para finalizar!", "success");
                //swal("Planificación Creada Correctamente!", "Da Clic en el boton para finalizar!", "success");
                //TablaJson(data) // Se ejecutará en el caso de que el proceso sea completado
            } else {
                console.log("¡ Error en la transacción ")
                swal ( "Oops" ,  "A ocurrido un error en el proceso!: \n Descripción: "+ data['error'] ,  "error" )
            }
    }
    }).done(function(response){ //
        $("#server-results").html(response);
    });
});

HTML
```

```html
<form action="/actividad/planificacion/guardarplanificacion/" method="post" id="my_form">
  <div class="table-responsive" style="min-height: .01%; overflow-x: auto;">
    <table id="mainTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover js-basic-example dataTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 30%">ACTIVIDAD</th>
          <th>COBERTURA</th>
          <th>RESPONSABLE</th>
          <th>REQUERIDO </th>
          <th>FECHA INICIO </th>
          <th>FECHA FIN </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>ACTIVIDAD</th>
          <th>COBERTURA</th>
          <th>RESPONSABLE</th>
          <th>REQUERIDO </th>
          <th>FECHA </th>
          <th>FECHA </th>

        </tr>
      </tfoot>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <hr />
  <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <button id="guardar_boton" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect" type="submit" ">GUARDAR</button>
                        </div>

                        </div>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Saludos es porque no estas enviado el **ajax** con el **token** respectivo podrias hacer algo así:

```
    /**
     * Permite obtener el token de django
     * 
     */
    function getCookie(name) {

      var cookieValue = null;
      if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
          var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
          for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
              var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
              if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
              cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                  break;
              }
          }
      }
      //RETORNANDO EL TOKEN
      return cookieValue;

    }//end function getCookie

/*EJEMPLO AJAX HACIA DJANGO*/
        //token
        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mi_url",
            data:{
                csrfmiddlewaretoken : csrftoken, 
                parametro1:valor1,
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
             console.log(data);
            },
            error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {

                    alert('Error al intentar Conectarse: Verifique su conexion a Internet.');

                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {

                    alert('La Pagina solicitada no fue encontrada [404]');

                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {

                    alert('Erro Interno [500]');

                } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {

                    alert('Error en el retorno de Datos. [parseJson]');

                } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {

                    alert('Tiempo de Espera agotado');

                } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {
                    alert('Solicitud Abortada. [Ajax Request]');

                } else {
                    alert('Error desconocido: ' + jqXHR.responseText);

                }//end if 

            }//end error
        });
```

Si te fijas tengo una funcion que se encarga de obtener el token y luego se la envio x ajax para mayor referencia te facilito el link: [Ajax Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#ajax)

Espero te sirva suerte..!!